# Shell script to extract unique strings from filenames or from content of XML documents

Tags: bash, shell, xml-parsing, compare

Using a bash shell script, I would like to take a directory listing of files and only list unique instances of a specific string.

The string (for example `0082230958089736545`) can be found in 2 places

1. The filename (in the 4th section, the longest number)

   ```
   AVAILITY.VT04.00090.0082230958089736545.72732411.20121017.053604220
   ```
2. Inside the XML Document

   ```
   <ENVELOPE>
   <HEADER>
   <ProviderTransID>0082230958089736545</ProviderTransID>
   </HEADER>
   <ENVELOPE>
   ```

In the filename, the first 4 sections (including the section with the string I want to compare) is the same, whereas the last 3 sections change as those identify the process date and time the file was retried.

Each instance of the string can be repeated up to 24 times. Right now I have to manually make sure I grab each instance of the string with my eyes, and I don't always trust those LOL.

I want to generate a list of each string with no repetitions, then assign each string to its own variable for use later on in the script.

As long as it can be done in a Bash shell script, I don't care if the string is extracted from the filename or from the content of the .XML document.

Comment: What have you tried? We don't write code for you, we help you fix the problems in your code.

Comment: Hint: the `cut` and `sort -u` commands.

Comment: Which is the section you want to use to decide uniqueness? You want to match entire<br/>
AVAILITY.VT04.00090.0082230958089736545.72732411.20121017.053604220<br/>
OR<br/>
AVAILITY.VT04.00090.0082230958089736545<br/>
OR<br/>
72732411.20121017.053604220
?

Comment: i want the 0082230958089736545 or 4th section to decide uniqueness

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method accesses only the filenames. Add either of the following to your shell script:

```
IFS=$'\n'
array=($(awk -F "." '!a[$5]++ { print $5 }' <(find . -type f)))
```

or:

```
IFS=$'\n'
array=($(cut -d "." -f 5 <(find . -type f) | sort -u))
```

---

You can access the elements of the array using an array slice. To access the first element for example:

```
echo "${array[0]}"
```

Alternatively you can loop through all the elements using a for loop:

```
for i in "${array[@]}"; do
    echo "$i"
done
```

Comment: +1 for `cut`. Though, doesn't he want `-f 4` for the forth field?

Comment: @Tilman: `find` naturally returns the path of a file, like `./file.txt`. I could do some trickery to set `-f 4` by adding `-printf "%p\n"` to the `find` command, but it seems superfluous.